# Firestore emulator: can't see documents in UI using host 0.0.0.0

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm using [firebase-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools) v9.0.1 on Windows, using NVM for Windows v1.1.7 with Node v14.15.2.

I've successfully installed and can run the emulators for firestore, functions and auth. I've populated firestore with data using the emulator UI, and used `firebase emulators:export test_data` to export some test data. I now use this when starting the emulators with `firebase emulators:start --import test_data` so that I see all my test data after restarts in the emulator UI.

The weirdness starts when I change the host in firebase.json to 0.0.0.0 so that I can connect my flutter app running on a real device to the emulators:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"   <-- this is added
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"   <-- this is added
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

When I do this, and restart the emulators, they start successfully, and I can access the UI - but all the documents are just gone. I can see all the collections, just not any documents. However, the device CAN see the documents - so they are there, it's just that the UI isn't showing them. The device can even add documents (which also don't appear in the UI). If I export the data again, then restart the emulators without host `0.0.0.0`, hey presto all the documents appear again, with the ones added using the device.

What seems to be happening is that when I run using host 0.0.0.0 the UI has no permissions to see any of the documents. Is this expected or is this a bug? Is there any way around this? The emulator doesn't seem to have any security rules so I'm kind of stuck.

**EDIT**

After firing up developer console I can see this on the emulator UI page:

> VM6:1 POST
> http://0.0.0.0:8080/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2Fmyproject%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&RID=9716&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=SomeRedactedStuff
> net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

So I guess the problem is that the UI is looking for firebase on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. I'm not sure how to resolve that.

Comment: If you think there is a bug in the emulator, file an issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Thanks, I've just opened an issue [https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2959](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2959)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that [this was a bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2964), which is now fixed in firebase-tools v9.1.0. If you have the CLI installed globally, check you version with:

```
npm outdated -g --depth=0
```

If you have an earlier version, for example:

```
Package          Current   Wanted   Latest  Location 
firebase-tools   9.0.1     9.1.0    9.1.0   global
```

Update using:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```